# Extract Chart data from excel using JS

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using [excel.js](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) to convert **.XLSX file** to **HTML**.

```
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook()

workbook.xlsx.readFile("./file.xlsx").then(wb => {
  wb.eachSheet(sheet => {
    //Sheet Data here
    sheet.eachRow(row => {
      //Row Data here
      row.eachCell(cell => {
        //Cell Data here
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I can fetch all the cells with strings, but it completely skips cells with charts. Is there any way I could get the chart data using excel.js or any other library? Would appreciate any help.